# How to get max value, average, min, count from one column based on a unique id from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
    SELECT  [Student ID]
      ,[Course ID]
      ,[Name]
      ,max[Marks]
      ,[Grade]
  FROM [CE].[dbo].[GradeCount]
  order by [Student ID]
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: **TYPO alert**: it's a **column** - not a "coloum" .....

Answer (score 1):

use aggregation and group by

```
 SELECT [Student ID]
      ,[Course ID]
      ,[Name]
      ,max([Marks])
      ,max([Grade])
  FROM [CE].[dbo].[GradeCount]
 group by [Student ID] ,[Course ID],[Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `GROUP BY` fields you want to use aggregation functions such as `MAX`, `MIN`, `AVG`, `COUNT`:

```
  SELECT 
    MAX(course_ID) MaxCourse_ID
  , MIN(course_ID) MinCourse_ID
  , AVG(course_ID) AvgCourse_ID
  , COUNT(course_ID) CountCourse_ID
  FROM [CE].[dbo].[GradeCount]
  group by course_ID
```